# How to prevent web crawlers in your PHP file

Tags: php, web-crawler

How to prevent web crawlers in your PHP file?

Comment: Web crawlers can't see your PHP

Comment: How would you know if you're being crawled?

Comment: You would check your access.log firstly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `robots.txt` within the following and place it on the root folder of your website.

It will tell to all `User-agent` to do not crawl any PHP file (`Disallow: /*.php$`)

Robots.txt content:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /*.php$
```

Also read: http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

Comment: Although this is just politely asking them not to. It doesn't actually stop them from doing so if they choose to ignore your wishes.